# Laravel cache for every device

Tags: php, laravel, caching, local-storage

I am trying to cache products name which users add to basket and i want to make it works for anonymous users(for everyone). I tried laravel cache but i don't know how to make unique key for caching and i can take that unique key for that user and show their products.

```
        Cache::put('MyBasket',$arr);
```

I used that code but it would show same result for everyone who visit website of course . I can make it for registered users with their id but i want to make it for everyone (non-registered users ).
Maybe can i use mac address or something like that ?

Comment: What about using ip address?

Comment: Wouldn't it show same result for chrome and firefox ? I mean browsers

Comment: yes if connected to same internet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use session Id, laravel internally maintains its uniqueness

```
Cache::put(session()->getId(),$arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have mentioned that your project has products. Generally, for E-Commerce based applications caching is not give you a good result. You may try to save your products in session or cookie. If you didn't saved the user products inside database, Session storage will be very helpful to you. Try with Laravel Sessions

Comment: Okey I will try .But how about key ? If i use IP it would be same result for different browsers

Comment: Yes, IP will give you same result. But IP will be changed for every time when the router restarts. It will not give you a better solution.

Comment: To generate key for the users you may try php random string generations or You can use session_id

Comment: if i generate key how will know that key . I want to do it for non-users too

Comment: If you are not using REST API save the data in a session variable and call it back to get their own products. The user will can see their own products only because session will be stored in local computer. If you are using Rest Api, You may use Local storage. it will do the same. No anyone can see any other data except their own product

Comment: Thanks for explanation and your quick answers ^_^. I would try sessions if i can't find any other way with my current code.